# Replicating a form post in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

Browser will send data to NodeJS. From NodeJS, I need to redirect to another site. It should be a post request with some request body value to be passed.

How should I do this?

=================
Update

From client, I am making an ajax post request. Node should then redirect the browser to another url (as if client is doing form post).

Comment: maby node-http-proxy can help

Comment: It is for creating a proxy server right? Not sure how that will help

Comment: what do you mean with redirect? should the browser send another request or should the server proxy the request to another server?

Comment: it should do a browser redirect, like the same way, if I am doing submitting a form from a browser with method POST. Only difference is, it should be happen from NodeJS.                                                            So, for the end user, what happens is, when he click on a button, it will redirect to another page as if he is submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

if i right understand, you need something like this?

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser   = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024}));

app.get('/some_route', function (req, res) {
    request.post('http://www.google.com', {json: req.body}, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           res.send(body);
        } else {
            res.send("SOME ERROR");
        }
    })
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
})
```

Comment: This will not do a browser redirect. So, this will not be useful for me I guess.